# Most efficient way to transform this data using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have several hundred .csv files in the format shown on the left below, and I need to transform them all into the format shown on the right. I tried to highlight the blocks of data to make it easier to see what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Is there an efficient way to do this using Pandas? I was trying to formulate something using df.iteritems() but couldn't think of a good way to do it.

Comment: Can you provide some dummy data of 2 tables

Comment: + actually it is just some basic ETL :-/

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
       Date-Time  L-A
0  5/1/2022 0:00  1.4
1  5/1/2022 0:05  1.4
2  5/2/2022 0:10  1.4
```

Doing:

```
name = df.columns[1]
df['x'] = name
df = df.reindex(columns=['x', 'Date-Time', name])
print(df.values)
```

Output:

```
[['L-A VLX' '5/1/2022 0:00' 1.4]
 ['L-A VLX' '5/1/2022 0:05' 1.4]
 ['L-A VLX' '5/2/2022 0:10' 1.4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

My beginner's level way.

Slicing by column index location, later adding them together using concat:

```
print(df) # initial data frame
  DateTime  Units DateTime  Units
0        a      1     a111     10
1        b      2     b222     20
2        c      3     c333     30
```

**Slicing by column index location as the initial DF has duplicated headers:**

```
df2 = df.iloc[: , [0, 1]].copy()
df3 = df.iloc[: , [2, 3]].copy()
# adding all back into new DF
df_result = pd.concat([df2,df3]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_result)
```

output:

```
  DateTime  Units
0        a      1
1        b      2
2        c      3
3     a111     10
4     b222     20
5     c333     30
```